# innerHTML em uma TR de uma table JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá eu gostaria de gerar uma tabela dinamica no java script(apenas os tr e os td) para isso estou usando o innerHTML.

Eu faço o seguinte codigo:

```
objDiv1 = document.getElementById("tabela");

 bloco += "<tr><td>"+ Campo+"</td></tr>";

objDiv1.innerHTML = bloco;
```

Está gerando certo o html porém está jogando acima da minha tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu pegar e dar um console.log e colar no lugar onde está essa div vai funcionar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha estrutura do html está assim:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class=" text-primary">
    <th>
        Lote
    </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<div id="tabela"> 
</div>
</tbody>

</table>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Acredito que o mais errado seja colocar uma `div` dentro de uma tabela, isso realmente é necessário?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam qual seria a outra forma de eu passar um id e adicionar os tr e os td?

Comment: Adiciona direto no tbody ou na table em si

Comment: Não se deve usar div dentro de tabela, e se for usar mude o display dela pra display:table-cell, pode ser que funcione apesar de não ser o correto...

Comment: Você pode mudar de innerHTML pra outerHTML, deve funcionar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei algo rápido e descrevi cada etapa da melhor forma possível para você entender, no meu exemplo utilizei um formulário... fiz com javascript puro assim como seu código, mas aconselho você a utilizar o jquery.

```html
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
<body>

<script>
 function adicionar()
 {

    //Recupera as informações do campo dos formulários
    var codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
    var nome   = document.getElementById('nome').value;

    //Encontra o elemento tabela
    tabela = document.getElementById("tabela");

    //Inclui uma linha no elemento tabela <tr></tr>
    //informei -1 para criar a linha no final da tabela
    var linha   = tabela.insertRow(-1);

    //Adiciona dua coluna na linha criada <td></td> <td></td>
    var coluna1 = linha.insertCell(0);
    var coluna2 = linha.insertCell(1);

    //Inclui o valor do campo do formulário em sua respectiva coluna
    coluna1.innerHTML = codigo;
    coluna2.innerHTML = nome;
 }
</script>

<form>

    <label for="codigo">Código</label>
    <input type="text" id="codigo">

    <label for="codigo">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome">

    <input type="button" onclick="return adicionar();" value="Cadastrar">
</form>

<table id="tabela" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Codigo</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Raphael</td>
    </tr>
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Também pode só usar o innerHTML, por ser mais simples. Mas é basicamente isso mesmo (apesar de não concordar com o uso do jQuery), se quiser também pode colocar o id em um `tbody` dentro da tabela, para deixar mais organizado

Comment: Guilherme porque você não concorda com a utilização do jquery?

Comment: Se você tem uma aplicação que só aumenta uma tabela, não precisa usar jQuery, seria adicionar complexidade e dependências desnecessárias. Se não é só isso, é algo mais complexo, provavelmente também não deveria usar, jQuery quase sempre deixa código poluído e bagunçado, ele é ótimo, **pra design**

Comment: Só uma pergunta você não utiliza nenhum framework em seus projetos, seja front ou backend?

Comment: Uso, quando é uma página estática, uso jQuery, Typed, Velocity, ... Em sistemas uso AngularJS ou Angular (mas também estou disposto, e quero, a usar Vue e React). No backend também uso, express, PHPMailer, [meu framework](https://costamilam.github.io/PHP-Framework/). Só acho o jQuery desnecessário para sistemas simples, e não suficiente para sistemas mais complexos